# Position 2 UITabBarItem to left and right of screen, with void in the middle

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbaritem

Is there a way to position 2 `UITabBarItem` to the left and right of a `UITabBarController` and leave space in the middle as if there was 2 "unused" items? `itemPositioning`, `itemWidth` and `itemSpacing` don't seem to work that way.

The code below just splits the entire width of the screen in two equal parts, and position each item in the middle of its respective half:

```
class MainController: UITabBarController {
   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
                
      let vcOne = UIViewController()
      let vcTwo = UIViewController()
    
      let itemOne = UITabBarItem()
      itemOne.image = UIImage(named: "imgOne")

      let itemTwo = UITabBarItem()
      itemOne.image = UIImage(named: "imgTwo")

      vcOne.tabBarItem = itemOne
      vcTwo.tabBarItem = itemTwo
    
      tabBar.itemPositioning = .centered
      tabBar.itemWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 4
      tabBar.itemSpacing = UIScreen.main.bounds.width / 2
   }
}
```

I'm basically looking for something like this:

[image]

I guess I could use `UIEdgeInsets` but I'm looking for something more reliable to match the position of items in the same `UITabBar`, should it hold 4 items instead of 2.

Comment: Have you tried just adding two disabled `UITabBarItem`s with no image or title in the middle?

Comment: Yeah actually it was that simple. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add two disabled `UITabBarItem`s with no image or title in the middle.